# How to split one into multiple in spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to split a record having nested data into multiple records.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1','[{price:100, quantity:1},{price:200, quantity:2},{price:900, quantity:3},{price:500, quantity:5},{price:100, quantity:1},{price:800, quantity:8},{price:700, quantity:7},{price:600, quantity:6}]'),('2','[{price:100, quantity:1}]')],['id','data'])
```

Input data looks like

```
id,data
1,[{price:100, quantity:1},{price:200, quantity:2},{price:900, quantity:3},{price:500, quantity:5},{price:100, quantity:1},{price:800, quantity:8},{price:700, quantity:7},{price:600, quantity:6}]
2,[{price:100, quantity:1}]
```

Expected is to split the records if the array column contains more than 5 records and provide and id2 for each row

```
id,id2,data
1,1,[{price:100, quantity:1},{price:200, quantity:2},{price:900, quantity:3},{price:500, quantity:5},{price:100, quantity:1}]
1,2,[{price:800, quantity:8},{price:700, quantity:7},{price:600, quantity:6}]
2,1,[{price:100, quantity:1}]
```

I tried exploding the array column but getting new row with each element i.e. for id 1 getting 8 rows instead of 2.

How can it be done so that it gets exploded such that each row contains minimum 5 records in array?

Comment: i can think of one way. first do explode and then use rank function. It'll give rank among same id (hoping it'll incremental id2s for same id), then divide the new rank by 5 and based on that do group by.

Comment: Will surely try this, I was hoping for a much simpler approach. @shaileshgupta

Comment: A flatmap should work right, where if there are more records, u can produce list of rows.

Comment: are you looking for a StringType column or an array of structs column?

Comment: It's array of structs @jxc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Spark 2.4+, you can use SparkSQL builitin functions [sequence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#sequence) + [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) and do some math on the array indices:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('1','[{price:100, quantity:1},{price:200, quantity:2},{price:900, quantity:3},{price:500, quantity:5},{price:100, quantity:1},{price:800, quantity:8},{price:700, quantity:7},{price:600, quantity:6}]'),('2','[{price:100, quantity:1}]')],['id','data'])

N = 5

# for data column, convert String into array of structs
df1 = df.withColumn("data", F.from_json("data", "array<struct<price:int,quantity:int>>",{"allowUnquotedFieldNames":"True"}))

df1.selectExpr("id", f"""
    inline_outer(
      transform(
        sequence(1,ceil(size(data)/{N})), i ->
        (i as id2, slice(data,(i-1)*{N}+1,{N}) as data)
      )
    )
 """).show(truncate=False)
+---+---+--------------------------------------------------+
|id |id2|data                                              |
+---+---+--------------------------------------------------+
|1  |1  |[[100, 1], [200, 2], [900, 3], [500, 5], [100, 1]]|
|1  |2  |[[800, 8], [700, 7], [600, 6]]                    |
|2  |1  |[[100, 1]]                                        |
+---+---+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Never used sequence before, this provides the expected output. Thanks :)